# How to make a required="required" HTML5 in input type range

Tags: html, validation

Hello and could make a required HTML5 in input type range

```
<form>

    <input type="range" min="1" max="10" value="" required="required" />
    <input type="submit">

</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `required` attribute does not [apply](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/forms.html#concept-input-apply) to an `input` element in `Range` state.

> The value sanitization algorithm is as follows: If the value of the element is not a valid floating-point number, then set it to the best representation, as a floating-point number, of the default value.
>
> The default value is the minimum plus half the difference between the minimum and the maximum, unless the maximum is less than the minimum, in which case the default value is the minimum.
>
> [`Range` state (`type=range`)](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/forms.html#range-state-(type=range))

Answer (score 1):

You will never reuire `required`  attribute because `Validation/required` is irrelevant since a slider will always have a valid value - the UI slider does not allow for selecting invalid values.

For more baout `range` http://www.wufoo.com/html5/types/8-range.html

Answer (score 0):

This needs an answer. Required means **required** to be answered by a user through active participation, not because of default values on a scale.

ie. The rules of html forms were originally intended to follow survey and research methodology design principles, NOT coding quirks. HTML forms were built to meet real-world form requirements not the other way around.

If you create a form and want a range to be explicitly answered before the form can be submitted, you can add a self-contained workaround into the range input.

Simply do the following:

1. Add a standard text input field which is set to required but is hidden from view with with class=d-none / or css display:none. Do not use type=hidden, as this won't support this workaround. Insert this input after the input range field.
2. In the input type=range field, add a javascript method to remove the 'required' property of the hidden field with onChange.

in code terms:

```html
<input type="range" id="rangeinput" name="rangeinput" min="0" max="50" 
     onchange="$('#'+this.id+' + input').prop('required',false);"
     value="0">

<input type="text" class="d-none" value="" required>`
```

This will prevent the form from being submitted until the user changes the initial value of the range input. However, it will not 'focus' the range input to alert the user that this field was not attempted.

Feedback for the user can be provided, but depends on your preferred messaging approach.. whether it's toasts, popups, text fields, etc.

Comment: Hey thanks for answering! Your workaround could be helpful but I'd 1) get rid of jquery and only use js, and 2) test it out and maybe provide a jsfiddle or something cause I'm not sure it'd as is

Comment: Thanks for your edit suggestions. The original question doesn't specify pure JS, so the jquery vs js debate ("purist vs pragmatist") is beyond the scope of the question. The gist of my response is the use of a workaround approach. Cheers.

Comment: The original question doesn't even mention js. Just html. Which means if you suggest a workaround that uses js, you should specifically state that fact in your answer. Something like "if you're open to use js, you could try this". Now your answer not only uses js, but jQuery, which is an external library the user should import in order for your code to work. Again, at least state the fact that you're using jQuery. Or you could provide a vanilla js version, and a jQuery one. But always stating that you use jQuery in the latter

Comment: With respect, if a pure HTML solution is implied then both JS and JQuery solutions become equally unacceptable. However, because there are no pure HTML options and no constraints have been noted, all other pragmatic approaches are on the table. You are arguing on the merits of an absolute hierarchy of correctness for solution based on philosophical preference. But the key issue is my solution is the *approach* first and code second.. That's made clear in my layout.

Comment: I'm not arguing on anything. Just trying to give you some advice on how to answer on this site. Take it or leave it